# select data using stored procedure

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I use the stored procedure to get multiple records which that condition satisfies

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_GetAttendanceBwDates]
@datefrom datetime,
@dateto datetime,
@empid int

ASBEGIN`
select AM.employee_Id,CONVERT(varchar(10),AM.date,111) from
tblAttendanceMaster AM where AM.employee_Id=@empid and
CONVERT(varchar(10),AM.date,111)<=CONVERT(varchar(10),@datefrom,111)
and CONVERT(varchar(10),AM.date,111)=CONVERT(varchar(10),@dateto,111)
END
```

in code behind,when execute the below code I getting the error.I didn't understand it

```
var objattendance = context.Sp_GetAttendanceBwDates(datefrom,dateto,emp);
```

error message

```
occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code.
   Additional information: The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'FlairModel.Sp_GetAttendanceBwDates_Result'. A member of the type, 'record_Id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess theer is problem in the column i.e. property get created when you imported SP in you entiry frameowrk ,

So there might be problem with your select statement here which is not returning proper name matching with that generated complex type or generated type

for example this query with matching columns like

```
select AM.employee_Id as record_Id''need to be matching property name,
CONVERT(varchar(10),AM.date,111) as date''need to be matching property name
from
tblAttendanceMaster AM where AM.employee_Id=@empid and
CONVERT(varchar(10),AM.date,111)<=CONVERT(varchar(10),@datefrom,111)
and CONVERT(varchar(10),AM.date,111)=CONVERT(varchar(10),@dateto,111)
```

Comment: I try it like this..But i getting error as
`{"The function import 'FlairEntities.Sp_GetAttendanceBwDates' cannot be executed because it is not mapped to a store function."}`